# How can I relate a primary key field to multiple tables?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, composite-primary-key

I have 4 tables:

```
User 
Reports 
Photos 
Locations
```

I am allowed to report photos, users, and locations.

The primary key of my `Reports` table is (`User_Id, Reported_Id`)

`Reported_Id` could belong to any of these 3: `photos`, `users` and `locations`.

How can I represent this relationship in an entity relationship model?

Comment: You **cannot** do this - a foreign key (`Reported_Id`) cannot reference three tables at once - or one of three depending on some other column in your table. Just cannot be done.

Comment: I think @marc_s might be not totally correct; but it's hard making out the requirements here. "`Reported_Id` could belong to ... `users` ..." So the `Reports` table could have a primary key of 2 `User_Id`s? Must they be the same? I think there must be 2 relationships between entities `Reports-Users`: all `Reports` belong to some `User` (that's element 1 of the key); some `Users` appear on `Reports` (that's element 2 of the key). Can we say every `photo/user/location` must appear on some report? (that's a foreign key from each of those 3 entities to `Reports` element 2.)

Comment: Tables represent relation(ship)s/associations. A FK "relationship" tells the DBMS that subrows appear elsewhere as PK/UNIQUE. You don't have that. This is an anti-pattern for subtyping. This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Also various ER methods model this in different ways.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Answer (score 4):

### The Problem

> <sub>You cannot do this - a foreign key (Reported_Id) cannot reference three tables at once</sub>

Seems to be a problem regarding the understnading of the data ... rather than a technical problem regarding an FK pointing to three PKs.

> <sub>or one of three depending on some other column in your table. Just cannot be done.</sub>

That is not correct.  Such a requirement is fairly straight-forward in a Relational database:

- the *Relational Model* is logical, it is founded on First Order Predicate Calculus (aka First Order Logic).
  Having a solid mathematical basis gives it great power.
- the *relations* are logical creatures
  Physical `Record IDs` are not logical
- there is no limit to what can be defined in FOL,
  there is nothing that can**not** be defined in FOL
  therefore there is nothing that can**not** be defined in a Relational database (and of course SQL, its data sublanguage)
  .

  > <sub>Note that what the "theoreticians" promote and market as "relational" is in fact a 1960's Record Filing System, which has none of the Relational Integrity; Relational Power; or Relational Speed that a database that complies with the *Relational Model* has.  Such systems are identified by their use of physical `Record IDs`.  In such primitive systems, yes, data is not logical, and logical relations or relationships cannot be defined.  Further, the SQL code required is horrendous.</sub>

What you are seeking in a logic article, an **OR Gate**.  The specific nature of the OR Gate (there are several forms) needs to be defined: that is the modelling exercise.

### The Data

Forget about `ID` columns, that will only serve to cripple the data modelling exercise.  Concentrate on the data,  what the data means, and what other data it relates to.  Perhaps you are trying to declare something along these lines (these are FOPC/FOL **Predicates**):

- Each User is Independent
- Each Photo is Independent
- Each Location is Independent
- Each User makes 0-to-n Reports
- Each Report is **any** of { Photo | Location | User }

That is very loose, we can tighten it up.  Let's proceed to ...

### Entity Relation • Subtype

This data model (ER level) implements a **Non-Exclusive Subtype** cluster for Report.

[image: MixtureSub]

**All** Predicates are explicit in an IDEF1X data model, and thus can be *read* from it, however, I have given the relevant Predicates *in text form* on the right.

#### Notation

- All my data models are rendered in [IDEF1X](https://www.idef.com/idef1x-data-modeling-method/), the Standard for modelling Relational databases since 1993
- My [IDEF1X Introduction](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Introduction.pdf) is essential reading for beginners
- The [IDEF1X Anatomy](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Model%20Anatomy.pdf) is a refresher for those who have lapsed.
- **Non-Exclusive Subtype** - refer to [Subtype](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Article/Database/Relational%20Model/Subtype.pdf) for full details on Subtype implementation.

  - for contrast or interest re **Exclusive Subtype**, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58484236/484814).

### Entity Relation • Optional Column

The above implements the Predicate:

- Each Report is **any** of { Photo | Location | User }

meaning that a Report must be at least one of { Photo | Location | User }.

However, if that is not the case, if Report can be *none* of { Photo | Location | User }, that means { Photo | Location | User } are each Optional Columns.

[image: MixtureOpt]

### Determination

> <sub>one of three depending on some other column in your table</sub>

Determining which, or all, the Subtypes or Optional Columns that are used for each Report is not an issue:

- **Exclusive Subtype**
  Yes, that does require a **Discriminator** column in the Basetype.
- **Non-Exclusive Subtype**
  There are multiple Subtypes for the Basetype, therefore a Discriminator column in the Basetype is irrelevant.

  - Determination is via a `SELECT` from the Subtype table (which, by definition, has the exact same PK as the Basetype table).
- **Optional Column**
  An indicator in the Basetype would be redundant.

  - Determination is via a `SELECT` from the Optional Column table (ditto).
  - Generally, one would create a `VIEW` for the Basetype, eg `Report_V`, and include all possible columns.

Comment: @Mixture Please evaluate this answer.